# button mapping/shortcuts gets reset after shout down

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I've been using Juno for a few months, about 3 weeks ago this issue occurs out of the blue, all media keys don't work, same for custom shortcuts. until I reassign them again from `tweaks` or `dconf-editor`. but I'm back to square one after shutdown/reboot.